# python generator function that is allowed to iterate over mutations

Tags: python, generator, iterable

I want to define a generator function that can iterate through a dictionary object that is mutating.

```
def generator(d):
    for k,v in sorted(d.items()):
        yield (k,v)

d = {1:'a', 2:'x', 4:'m', 8:'d', 16:'f'}
i = generator(d)
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
del d[8]
print(next(i))
d[16] = "f"
d[32] = "z"
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
```

If I execute the code above, I will get:

```
(1, 'a')
(2, 'x')
(4, 'm')
(8, 'd')
(16, 'f')
```

The desired output should be:

```
(1, 'a')
(2, 'x')
(4, 'm')
(16, 'f')
(32, 'z')
```

The part I don't understand is when I assign `d = {1:'a', 2:'x', 4:'m', 8:'d', 16:'f'}` to `i = generator(d)` The dictionary is already added into function `generator(d)` and becomes a generator instance with the initial dictionary. So whenever I use `del` function, the generator stays unchanged with `d = {1:'a', 2:'x', 4:'m', 8:'d', 16:'f'}` as its parameter. How am I gonna achieve this?

Comment: You cannot safely do that. You might delete the item the iterator just returned, which means the iterator is now pointing at the next time, but will advance its pointer anyway, or the item you add may be added earlier than the current position, and never seen.

Comment: The issue is `sorted(d.items())` returns a new dictionary that isn't `d`. Therefore when you `del d[8]`, your generator wont be affected since it's iterating through a new dictionary that isn't `d`. Not sure how to solve your issue though.

Comment: @Loocid: `sorted(d.items())` produces a list of tuples, not a dict. However, it is still not `d` and still not affected by changes to `d`.

Comment: can i ask do the items need to be sorted? it seems that the keys are unique the changes would have to be outputed anyway after other elemnets with highter keys when something else is change. What i mean is let's say instead of `d[16]` you decide to change `d[2] = 'u'` the output after 4,'m' would be 2,'u because the key value pair has changed, so what is sorted purpose

Comment: @jimakr items don't have to be sorted. The reason why I sorted it because I want to get minimum key which is not yielded every time.

Comment: ah ok, if it was needed i would have to use a library but now everything works, wait i am writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to deal with exceptions to check when the dictionary is changed and a buffer to keep the keys already yielded.

```
def generator(d):
    buffer = set()
    while True:
        old_hash = hash(frozenset(d.items()))
        try:
            for k, v in d.items():
                if hash(frozenset(d.items())) != old_hash:
                    raise RuntimeError('dictionary changed size during iteration')
                if (k, v) not in buffer:
                    buffer.add((k, v))
                    yield k, v
            break
        except RuntimeError as e:
            if str(e) != 'dictionary changed size during iteration':
                raise e
```

when the dictionary is modified the exception causes the for loop to restart, skipping over key-values pairs already yielded, the outer loop restarts everything when the dictionary is changed and breaks when every element in d has been yielded.

The only thing you need to be aware of is that when every item is returned and the generator stops, a dictionary change won't restart it the way the code is right now

EDIT added hashes for catching a very specific case mentioned in comments

Comment: This doesn't handle cases where one entry is deleted and another is inserted.

Comment: for that case a simple hash would suffice but i will edit it in

Comment: Something wrong with this code, its not resetting the set every time its being yielded. Edited: My bad I didnt see a print statement inside the function

Comment: yeah sorry forgot the print was there i eddited out and added the hashing of the dictionary to check if values are being deleted and added before calling the function making python not detect the change in the dictionary

Comment: @jimakr would this print out the smallest key in the dictionary? it wouldn't right? If I need to yield the smallest key every time how could it be done?

Comment: you could change `yield` like this `yield k, v, sorted(d.items())[o]` but since d.items is already called before, i would save that to a variable to be more efficient. saying that i had not planned for the hash to be needed so i would alter this approach a lot if the min element had to be returned every time

Answer (score -1):

You need to yield by index instead of by element. You need to regenerate the list between each yield to capture changes.

```
def generator(d):
    for i in range(len(d)):
        dd = sorted(d.items())
        if i < len(dd):
           yield dd[i]
           
           
d = {1:'a', 2:'x', 4:'m', 8:'d', 16:'f'}
i = generator(d)
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
del d[8]
print(next(i))
d[16] = "f"
d[32] = "z"
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
```

Output

```
(1, 'a')
(2, 'x')
(4, 'm')
(16, 'f')
(32, 'z')
```

Comment: This is absurdly expensive and *still* doesn't actually work. Entries can still be skipped, and they can be double-counted if insertions happen.